# Silverlight Bing Maps - Pushpin

Tags: silverlight

How do I make the Silverlight Bing Maps pushpin larger? The reason I want to make it larger is so that I can add more content into the head of the pushpin. However, I cannot figure out how to add the content I want to the head of the pushpin without it being cut off.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own custom pushpin.  Have you tried doing that?

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/#MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.TutorialCustomPushpin

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete explaination of using the Pushpin and other methods of displaying graphics try: [Getting started with the Bing Maps Silverlight Control](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/silverlight/683-getting-started-with-the-bing-maps-silverlight-control-.html)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved this already, but as others have suggested you could make your own custom pushpin. That is usually the best approach.

The simplest answer to you question is to apply a ScaleTransform to your pushpin. That will be tricky since the content will also be affected.